# elasticesearch adding keyword not working

Tags: python, elasticsearch

error:

```
    {"timestamp": "2023-02-26T16:06:23.388759Z", "level": "INFO", "name": "denali_syncer.opensearch",
    "message": "create index cd.io.schema.asset mapping, status 400, body: b'{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":
    \"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: mapper [metadata.cloudAccountId] cannot 
    be changed from type [text] to [ObjectMapper]\"}],\"type\":\"mapper_parsing_exception\",\"reason\":\"Failed to parse
    mapping [_doc]: mapper [metadata.cloudAccountId] cannot be changed from type [text] to [ObjectMapper]\",\
    \"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"mapper [metadata.cloudAccountId] cannot be changed from type [text] 
    to [ObjectMapper]\"}},\"status\":400}'"}
```

Data for index mapping

```
{
    "cloudAccountId" : {"type" : "text"},
    "cloudAccountId.keyword" : {"type" : "keyword"},
}
```

Code:

```
url = f'{OPENSEARCH_URL}/{dataset}'
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=HEADERS, data=fields_json)
```

I am using  above code to create index and using keyword for sorting
I am getting above error

Please check how to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

Your index mapping should be something like this in order to work:

```
{
    "cloudAccountId" : {
       "type" : "text",
       "fields": {
         "keyword": { "type": "keyword" }
       }
    }
}
```